# Nodejs not part of docker in Getting Started Template for JSS to work

Tags: jss, docker

Nodejs is a pre-requisite for Sitecore 10 JSS and after setting up the solution for JSS with Getting started template https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html, an error is shown is experience editor on wiring up the react JSS app.

Is there a suitable option for Sitecore Docker so Nodejs is part of the setup?

Experience editor shows the following exception:

> Error Rendering
> Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer:
> Failed to start Node process. To resolve this: [1] Ensure that Node.js
> is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories. Current
> PATH environment variable is:
> C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
> Make sure the Node executable is in one of those directories, or
> update your PATH. [2] See the InnerException for further details of
> the cause.

Comment: This Getting Started template is specific to ASP.NET Core, but per answers below, it's pretty easy to add node to the `Dockerfile` for CM/CD roles.

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the end of dockerfile

```
# Download node package we want and unzip to one of search paths
RUN curl.exe -o node.zip https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.14.0/node-v12.14.0-win-x64.zip
RUN tar.exe -xf node.zip -C "C:\Windows" --strip-components=1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's located in the test folder from the docker-images repo. There is an example to show you how to do that.
https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-images/blob/master/build/windows/tests/10.0.x/build/jss-integrated-mode/Dockerfile

There are scenarios where people may prefer to use their own rendering engine instead of integrated mode.

Comment: Answer would be better if you included the specific lines from the Dockerfile to install node. :)